# How to create an object of a type *T given T is a generic type with the constraint proto.Message?

Tags: go, protobuf-go

I'm trying to implement a generic function with the signature `func[T proto.Message]()` in which the implementation instantiates an object of type `*T`. For example, the a call would look something like `f[*MyProtoMessage]()` (since the generated code has `*MyProtoMessage` implement `proto.Message` and `MyProtoMessage` does not).

Since `T` itself would be `*MyProtoMessage`, `new(T)` would return `nil`.

I've tried:

```
    it := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(lo.Empty[T]()))
    t := it.Interface()
```

but it errors with `reflect: call of reflect.Value.Interface on zero Value`.

Is there a way to create an object of type `*T`?

Comment: Have you tried `new(T)`?

Comment: Yes. I've added why that doesn't work.

Comment: If the type **argument** itself is a pointer type you can do: `rt := reflect.TypeOf(new(T)).Elem().Elem()` to get the base type of `T`, then `reflect.New(rt).Interface().(T)` to get the typed instance of `T`. Note, if the type argument can be both a pointer and a non-pointer, make sure to first check the `Kind` before doing "double Elem()". https://go.dev/play/p/amkHkOxx8Jk

Answer (score 1):

`lo.Empty[T]().ProtoReflect().New().Interface()` creates a pointer to a non-nil instance of the underlying type, `*T`.

Comment: For any future reader who wonders what `lo` stands for: it must be `https://github.com/samber/lo`, and the function called `Empty` is as simple as: 

func Empty[T any]() T {
 var zero T
 return zero
}